template friend: compilation fails with clang but works with gcc
This code compiles on gcc but not on clang. Which compiler is correct, and how to make it compile on clang-14, without modifying A's code?
Using clang v14.0.0 on Ubuntu 22.04.
It works on the latest unstable version on clang, not available in apt repos, and I would like to fix this code without having to install manually the toolchains just for this, since I expect not everybody will have the trunk version installed.
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

template<typename T>
class B
{
};

class A
{
    struct Sub {
        int r;
    };

    template<typename>
    friend class B;
};

template<>
struct B<int>
{
    template<typename T>
    using Sub = typename T::Sub;
};

int main()
{
    int i = offsetof(B<int>::Sub<A>, r);
}

error from clang 14.0.0:
<source>:23:5: error: 'Sub' is a private member of 'A'
    using Sub = typename T::Sub;
    ^
<source>:11:12: note: implicitly declared private here
    struct Sub {
           ^


wich versions? What flags? What error?

cannot reproduce https://godbolt.org/z/bjzzYKnKT

Compiles with all three compilers

With clang 18 or clang-14, it doesn't compile

@rafoo Always use the latest compilers(trunk version in godbolt). As you can see, it compiles with all 3 compilers. There is a site called godbolt these days, which allows us to use, trunk version of these compilers.

@rafoo When latest version of compiler start accepting the program, it is usually a sign that the program is well-formed. This is specially true when other compilers already accepted the program in older as well as newer versions.

@user12002570 "Always use the latest compilers." To be fair, Clang only fixed it in trunk. The latest stable rejects this.

The clang's version which compiles this code is not available in Ubuntu 22.04 apt repos...

@rafoo Yes, that is a limitation. Use godbolt.

I dont understand the reluctance to post the compiler error message for this type of question. Suppose someone used other compiler flags by accident and looks at an error message completely different from yours, what confusion there will be. Or someone uses a different version of the compiler...


Which compiler is correct

This is a fixed clang bug and the program is well-formed.
Note that clang trunk starts accepting the program. Demo
Here is the clang bug report:
Clang rejects valid friend access
